# Как подключить два и более файлов в Media Player

Tags: java, android

имеется некая кнопка, с айди "play_button" и Java код,

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio1_1);
```

Вопрос: Как передать несколько аудио файлов в MediaPlayer.create()?
Или создать несколько таких переменных, как mediaPlayer, но как-то так : **mediaPlayer,mPlayer;** и поочерёдно заносить файлы как таковое : **create(this, R.raw.audio1_1);**?

Но... По моему же мнению, это как-то слишком засоряет код, должен же быть вариант...

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь стандартный медиаплеер не поддерживает очередь треков из коробки. Вы можете написать свой класс, который будет хранить в себе плейлист и переключать аудио, или воспользоваться готовым решением, например ExoPlayer'ом. Там выполнена навигация по очереди и есть shuffle mode

Comment: Хорошо, Спасибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать что-то вроде плеера, то лучшим вариантом все таки будет [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), он имеет уже готовые уведомления для сейчас играющего медиа и поддержку андроидовских медиасессий